# how to create a break in a txt file to do a new row in R

Tags: r

I have a txt file that doesn't have jumps between rows.
The txt is like that

ID;YEAR;MOUNT;1D34;2022;1000;2D35;2021;1300

And I need create the data frame in R

ID  | YEAR  |  MOUNT

1D34| 2022  | 1000

2D35| 2021  | 1300

I want to create a new row every 3 elements separated by " ; "

Comment: do all the ID start with a number then followed by a letter then another number? or is your data complete such that there is no missing data? Which of the above is true?

Comment: My data is complete, I want  a new row every 3 elements separated by " ; "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
read.csv2(text = gsub("(([^;]+;){2}([^;]+));", "\\1\n", readLines('txt.file')))

    ID YEAR MOUNT
1 1D34 2022  1000
2 2D35 2021  1300
```

Comment: I take note of your complimentary `gsub` regex(s).

Answer (score 1):

using your data:

```
txt <- 'ID;YEAR;MOUNT;1D34;2022;1000;2D35;2021;1300'
```

and base `strsplit`

```
matrix(unlist(strsplit(txt_file, ';')), ncol =3, byrow=TRUE)
     [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   
[1,] "ID"   "YEAR" "MOUNT"
[2,] "1D34" "2022" "1000" 
[3,] "2D35" "2021" "1300"
```

then take to data.frame to further characterize your column data types.

Answer (score 0):

If `df.txt` is your text file, you can do this:

```
df = strsplit(readLines("df.txt"),";")[[1]]
setNames(as.data.frame(matrix(df[4:length(df)], ncol=3, byrow=T)), df[1:3])
```

Output:

```
    ID YEAR MOUNT
1 1D34 2022  1000
2 2D35 2021  1300
```

Comment: I note your `)[[1]]` making the `unlist` call unnecessary.